# Custom Tooltip kendo ui slider

Tags: kendo-ui, slider, tooltip

Here's a solution for modifying the tooltip of the kendo-ui slider depending on the value:

```
var text = [];
text.push("Text 1");
text.push("Text 2");
text.push("Text 3");
text.push("Text 4");

$("#slider").kendoSlider({
                min: 0,
                max: 3,
                smallStep: 1,
                largeStep: 1,
                value: 0,
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: text[0], // min-value text
                },
                slide: function (e) {
                        e.sender.options.tooltip.format = text[e.value];
                }
 });
```

It' a pitty you can't configure the tooltip as with the tooltip-widget.

Comment: Is this a trick question or you just saying ?

Comment: Just saying. Couldn't find a solution so I provided one.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution I was looking for.  Who cares if the answer is in your question.  It's what I was looking for.  So, thanks.  I upvoted your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're half way there. Lets say you needed to represent minutes and seconds as if you were editing a video. This example is for using a range slider.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KjABb/

```
var text = [];
var templateString = "#= formatToMinutesSeconds(selectionStart) # - #= formatToMinutesSeconds(selectionEnd) #";
var mediaLength = 229; //03:49      
function formatToMinutesSeconds(value) {
    return text[value];
}

var i = 0;
while (i <= mediaLength) {
    var date = new Date(null);
    date.setSeconds(i);
    var minutesSeconds = kendo.toString(date, "mm:ss");
    text.push(minutesSeconds);
    i++;
}

$("#clip-editor-slider").kendoRangeSlider({
    min: 0,
    max: mediaLength,
    smallStep: 1,
    largeStep: 60,
    tickPlacement: "both",
    tooltip: {
        template: kendo.template(templateString)
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you noticed that your ticks no longer show up?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a local variable called _sliderValue.  This is an arbitrary name.  Call it what you want.  In the slider "slide" event handler, set _sliderValue to **e.value**.  Your tooltip template can then access the value stored in the local variable.

```js
var _sliderValue = 0;
var template = kendo.template($("#sliderTemplate").html());

//$("#slider").load(function() {
$("#slider").kendoSlider({
    min: 0,
    max: 3,
    smallStep: 1,
    largeStep: 1,
    value: 0,
    tooltip: {template: template},
    slide: function (e) {
      _sliderValue = e.value;
    }
});
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<script id="sliderTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
  <div>Text #= _sliderValue #</div>
</script>

<div id="slider"></div>
```