# Escape percentage "%" in Kendo UI template

Tags: kendo-ui, escaping, kendo-template

I'm trying to escape percentage "%" in my Kendo UI template, can someone help.

[image: Error :(]
My Code:

```
$donePercentageInput.kendoSlider({
            increaseButtonTitle: "Right",
            decreaseButtonTitle: "Left",
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            smallStep: 1,
            largeStep: 5,
            tooltip: {
                template: kendo.template("#= value \\\\% #")
            }
        });
```

Have tried `//%` `////%` `\\%` `\\\\%` nothing works... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple one to fix. It is simply a case of where you are putting the `%` symbol.

if you change the template to:

```
  tooltip: {
                template: kendo.template("#= value #%")
            }
```

then that will work for you.

here is a demo:

http://dojo.telerik.com/iGoLOc

drag the top slider and you will see the tool tip.

by placing the `%` in the `#= #` you are asking keno to work out the value provided with this odd symbol added to it and it doesn't like it.

Comment: This is the correct answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377094/custom-tooltip-kendo-ui-slider  I was able to do computation within that defined template schema (i.e., `template: kendo.template("#= value - 1 #%")` ) would return the event value minus 1 in all cases, which is exactly what I needed.